# ¿Como optimizar una query que contiene dos subquery en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente query:

```
SELECT presupuestosd.partida,presupuestosd.valor, 
(SELECT SUM(presupuestosa.comprado) AS comprado FROM presupuestosa 
WHERE presupuestosa.obra=18 AND presupuestosa.empresa=1 AND  
presupuestosa.partida=presupuestosd.partida) AS c_cantidad,
(SELECT SUM(presupuestosa.compradov) AS compradov FROM presupuestosa 
WHERE presupuestosa.obra=18 AND presupuestosa.empresa=1 AND  
presupuestosa.partida=presupuestosd.partida) AS c_valores
FROM presupuestosd 
WHERE presupuestosd.obra=18 AND presupuestosd.empresa=1 ORDER BY 
presupuestosd.partida
```

Me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de optimizar la consulta, ya que por la cantidad de datos se demora como 40 segundos.
Si hay alguna idea, desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única optimización que puedo sugerirte en base a la información que aportas, es la de reemplazar las dos subconsultas por un único `JOIN` que retorne las sumatorias deseadas. Estaríamos reemplazando dos subconsultas por cada fila por una sola a nivel tabla, para cualquier otra mejora ya deberíamos estar analizando, estructuras de tablas, índices y query/explain plans.

```
SELECT  presupuestosd.partida,
        presupuestosd.valor,
        IFNULL(PSA.c_cantidad,0) AS c_cantidad,
        IFNULL(PSA.c_valores,0)  AS c_valores
    FROM presupuestosd 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  presupuestosa.empresa,
                presupuestosa.obra,
                presupuestosa.partida,
                SUM(presupuestosa.comprado) AS c_cantidad,
                SUM(presupuestosa.compradov) AS c_valores
                FROM presupuestosa 
                GROUP BY presupuestosa.empresa,
                    presupuestosa.obra,
                    presupuestosa.partida
        ) PSA
        ON PSA.empresa = presupuestosd.empresa
        AND PSA.obra = presupuestosd.obra
        AND PSA.partida = presupuestosd.empresa
    WHERE   presupuestosd.obra=18 
        AND presupuestosd.empresa=1 
    ORDER BY 
        presupuestosd.partida
```